# sklearn, ValueError: could not convert string to float, even if I'm not using strings

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to fit a Random Forest with sklearn. 
Everytime I run my algorithm, I encounter the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#DIV/0!'
```

Searching on StackOverFlow I found that it may be occurring because I am trying to divide by zero. To avoid it, I multiplied every value in the dataframe to 100 and I then substituted every 0 with a 1 instead: given the scale of the new values, that 1 would have been irrelevant, or at least this is what I thought. The code that I used is:

```
df = df.mul(100)
df = df.replace(0, 1)
```

What happens is that if I now try to fit my RF I get a new error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932-30.68464932'
```

I am 100% sure that I'm not using any string as a value in my dataset. 
Here's a little sample:

[image: Data head]

So my question now becomes: how to fix this problem?

**EDIT**

By using "df.info" I discovered that there was an object. I solved this issue with the following one-liner:

```
df = df.apply(lambda col:pd.to_numeric(col, errors='coerce'))
```

Now all the values are in the format "float64".
The problem is that now I get a new error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

Comment: What does `df.dtypes` show ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, with further research I found a second one-linear which solved my problem: now the fitting is successful.

```
df = df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)]
```